# Bearing missing in LYFT api

Tags: lyft-api

I was using the LYFT api`s for my project,I wanted to know if in the Lyft API we get the "BEARING" with the Latitude and Longitude?

Thanks in advance
Tapas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling the `/v1/rides/{id}` endpoint `bearing` is included in the `location` object.